# setVisibleRowCount not working

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager, jlist

```
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    public class Ui2 extends JFrame {
        JLabel l, l1;
        JFrame f;
        JPanel panel;
        JScrollPane scrollpane;
        int r;
        JList list;
        Ui2() {
            super("HADOOP GUI");
            panel = new JPanel();
            setContentPane(panel);
            panel.setSize(500, 500);
            SpringLayout x = new SpringLayout();
            panel.setLayout(x);
            DefaultListModel listmodel = new DefaultListModel();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                listmodel.addElement("Record" + i);
            }
            list = new JList(listmodel);

            list.setVisibleRowCount(5); // here is problem
            list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            scrollpane = new JScrollPane(list);
            x.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, scrollpane, 150, SpringLayout.WEST, panel);
            x.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, scrollpane, 30, SpringLayout.NORTH, panel);
            panel.add(scrollpane);
            Dimension d = list.getPreferredSize();
            d.width = 200;
            scrollpane.setPreferredSize(d);
            l1 = new JLabel("Default");
            x.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, l1, 150, SpringLayout.WEST, panel);
            x.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, l1, 300, SpringLayout.NORTH, panel);
            panel.add(l1);
            list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {

                }

            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: list.setVisibleRowCount(5);  when i add more than 5 values to jlist the no of rows shown are also increases accordingly . i want that jlist show only 5 rows and to see other values of jlist user has to scroll jlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the method: `setVisibleRowCount(int)` can't be used for JLists which are added to a JPanel which has set a Layoutmanager.

I rebuild your application a bit, since I couldn't get it working by using a `SpringLayout` (I admit, I never used it before). But with the `BorderLayout` it is working fine. You just have to wrap the `Scrollbar`, which contains the `JList` into a foreign `JPanel` for which you don't define a Layoutmanager. I think the reason is that the Layoutmanager will layout it components according to the available space, hence the `setVisisbleRowCount` will be ignored! But remember, components may be displayed differntly by using another LayoutManager. I personally suggest you to use the `BorderLayout` for simple arrangement (North, south, ... ), `FlowLayout` for a series of parallel components and the `GridbagLayout` for advanced arangements. This should be sufficient for almost all applications.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class Ui2 extends JFrame {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2464942276900547953L;
    private JLabel l1;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JScrollPane scrollpane;
    private JList<String> list;

    public Ui2() {
        super("HADOOP GUI");
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setContentPane(panel);
        panel.setSize(500, 500);

        DefaultListModel<String> listmodel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            listmodel.addElement("Record" + i);
        }

        list = new JList<String>(listmodel);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(5); // here is problem
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        scrollpane = new JScrollPane(list);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(scrollpane);
        panel.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        l1 = new JLabel("Default");
        panel.add(l1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {

            }

        });

    }
}
```

Comment: `It seems ... setVisibleRowCount(int) can't be used for JLists  added to a JPanel which has set a Layoutmanager.` - of course it can. The setVisibleRowCount() methods exists so a preferred size can be determined for the JList. SpringLayout is a complex layout manager to use and I'm guessing the OP hasn't set the constraints properly. `You just have to wrap the Scrollbar, which contains the JList into a foreign JPanel` there is no need to add the scrollpane to a panel first. You could, for example, just add the scrollPane to the NORTH of the BorderLayout.